# What's the logical flaw in my iteration method?

Tags: java, iteration, logic

When iterate() is first called i'm generating a random number between 1-1024 and then checking if that random number is equal to 1. If it is, then done = true and the return value should be 10. If it's not, then the value of x should be decremented (x now = 9). I then expect getRandNum() to be called again within iterate(), this time generating a random number between 1-512 and checking if it's equal to 1 etc, etc... until the return value for x can only be equal to 1.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
static boolean done = false;

public static int rand(int x) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(x) + 1;
}

public static int value(int x) {
    return (int) Math.pow(2, x);
}

public static int getRandNum(int x) {
    return rand(value(x));
}

public static int iterate() {
    int x = 10;
    do {
        if (getRandNum(x) == 1) {
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            if (x > 1) {
                x--;
            } 
            else {
                x = 1;
                done = true;
            }
        }
    } while (done = false);

    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(iterate()); 
}
```

}

Right now iterate() only returns 9. I need it to return anything from 1-10. There's clearly a logical error, but i can't see it.

Comment: `done = false` sets it to false. You're looking for `==`. Or better yet, `!done`.

Comment: yeah silly mistake by me but it still only returns 9

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No wait, you're right that fixed it. This code was my minimal reproducible example, but i accidentally made the change in my original code so i didn't see its effect. Thanks though, feeling kind of stupid :\

Comment: Not quite reproducible. There's no `main()` method and we don't have `Rng`. Anyway, glad you've worked it out.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it to what it should have been. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small error: you did `while(done = false)`. This assigns `done` to `false`. The correct way to do this is `while(!done)`.

```
public static int iterate() {
    int x = 10;
    do {
        if (getRandNum(x) == 1) {
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            if (x > 1) {
                x--;
            } 
            else {
                x = 1;
                done = true;
            }
        }
    } while (!done);

    return x;
}
```

If you do this it prints 1.